# check if input value not equal to integer then don't submit form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

i have a simple php email form, but i am getting spam emails. I have added a check input, User have to fill the input. If input value equal to 12 then submit the form, otherwise don't submit the form with a popup error.(Please do the math.)

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" required>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" required>
<input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="phone" required>

<div class="check">
   <label>6 x 2 =</label>
   <input type="text" name="not_robot" required="required">
</div>

<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

i am using php method below:

```
if(isset($_POST['not_robot']) !== 12 && isset($_POST['not_robot']) !== ''){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Please do the math, if you are human.");</script>';
}else{
    //email script here
}
```

when i submit form, error popup appear saying "Please do the math, if you are human", but after i close the popup, it also send email.
Any help appreaciated Thanks

P.S: if check method is possible using javascript or jquery it would be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check when submitting the form. Go with below code or link-

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b91n23Lz/138/)

HTML Code-

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" required>
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" required>
  <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="phone" required>

  <div class="check">
    <label>6 x 2 =</label>
    <input type="text" name="not_robot" required="required">
  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT Code-

```
$('form').submit(function() {
      if (parseInt($('input[name="not_robot"]').val()) == 12) {
        return true;
      }
      else{
        alert('You not enterd the correct value');
        return false;
      }
    });
```

Comment: That is not what was asked. 12 is only an example - also no point in returning a boolean after testing a boolean

Comment: @Shubham Thanks, your code is working but can I add an error message if value is not equal to 12?

Comment: @SajjadAhmad I have updated my code you can print any alert message in `else` part. Please upvote it or mark it correct if my answer helps you.

Comment: @ShubhamBaranwal Great but one more thing, it alerts only if i type a wrong number but if i dont type anything, it is not giving me alert.

Comment: @SajjadAhmad remove `required="required"` from you `input` element then it should work.

Comment: @ShubhamBaranwal I figured out. Thanks Man!

Comment: Your question was to test an integer - not a SPECIFIC integer -  there is no test for integer here other than the number 12

Comment: @mplungjan I know but I think user just wants this test case for their question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to test on the client:

Plain JS

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.querySelector("form").onsubmit=function(e) {
    var val = this.elements["not_robot"].value;
    return !isNaN(val) && parseInt(Number(val)) == val &&  !isNaN(parseInt(val, 10);
  }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $("form").on("submit",function(e) {
    var val = $("[name='not_robot'"].val();
    if (isNaN(val) || !parseInt(Number(val)) == val ||  isNaN(parseInt(val, 10)) e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to prevent sending spam mail this way. My suggestion is to apply csrf protection and also google captcha. You can use [this library](https://packagist.org/packages/volnix/csrf) for csrf protection. And for google captcha use [this](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/)

Comment: That depends on the target audience. The calculator is enough to stop harvesters but not dedicated spammers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate through PHP..Below is the way

```
if(is_numeric($_POST['not_robot']) && !empty($_POST['not_robot'])){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Please do the math, if you are human.");</script>';
}else{
    //email script here
}
```

Comment: This will not stop a submission

Answer (score 0):

**Ways :**

- Use [**PHP exit()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) function to exits the current script execution.we can use this function with (or without) an message.

  **Syntax :** `exit(message)` **`OR`** `exit()`
- We can also use `return;`

  Here, the control will return to the script that invoked the running of that file.

**Try this :**

```
if(isset(($_POST['not_robot']) != '12') && (isset($_POST['not_robot']) !== '')){
    /* alert here */
    exit();
}else{
    //email script here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form1">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" required>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" required>
<input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="phone" required>

<div class="check">
   <label>6 x 2 =</label>
   <input type="text" name="not_robot" id="not_robot" required="required" />
</div>

<input type="button" value="submit" onClick="checkForm()">
</form>
```

JavaScipt:

```
function checkForm()
{

  if(document.getElementById('not_robot').value == "12" && document.getElementById('not_robot').value != "")
  {
    alert('ok');
    document.forms['form1'].submit();
  }else{
        alert('not ok');
      }

}
```

Comment: He wants in PHP not JS

Comment: I've tested the code with JSFiddle and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/2t23x0ud/ The form doesn't submit if the math answer is wrong.