# Promo Code Validation

Tags: html

I need to validate a Promo Code for one of my html Booking form field. If the entered promo code is correct, users can submit the Booking details. Only one unique promo code. Something like "15OFFNOW" How should I do it? Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: i think you need a remote validation .  do you want check promo code in server site that it is unique or no ?

Comment: No just a normal validation is enough. I have tried with below code. <input class="form-control form-control-light bdr-2 rd-0" required data-label="Promo Code" data-msg="Please enter a valid promo code." type="text" name="promo-code" placeholder="Promo Code" pattern="15OFFNOW" required >

Answer (score 1):

First, don't put the promo code in your page. Anyone can see it.
[image]

I would do this, but it depends on actually functionality.

1. Do client side check (this can be bypassed by a malicious user)
2. Do server side check

**Do client side check**

Use a good non-reversible hashing [algorithm](https://github.com/Caligatio/jsSHA) and verify what you have in the prom text box to the hash you have stored in a JavaScript variable or in a data-hash attribute.

So if hash(text box value) == valueOf(data-hash), then proceed to sever validation.

**Do server side check**

In server no need of hash. Just check the post string with the promo code you have.

Answer (score 1):

i try your code

```
<form method="post">
    <input class="form-control form-control-light bdr-2 rd-0" required 
           data-label="Promo Code" 
           data-msg="Please enter a valid promo code." 
           type="text" name="promo-code" 
           placeholder="Promo Code" 
           pattern="15OFFNOW" required>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

validation is work .  show this message .

[image]

Comment: But not for me.

Comment: what is your browser  ? and version  ?

Comment: ignore html validation if you add jquery validation in your page . add it this page  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript for that , I fyou want to match promocode or you can validate it at backend using any backend language like PHP or java

for JQuery

```
//previous Ajax code here 
if($("#input_id").val() !== "15OFFNOW"){

   return false ;
}
 // here you can proceed for Ajax request
```

Comment: Or If you just want to validate like promocode can't be blank , Then there is    attribute called "required" use it in your html input

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an input pattern, also called regexp (though I would instead suggest doing it js way (but not global) or on server side as advanced users can simply inspect html code). Most probably something like this

```
<input type="text" name="promo" pattern="15OFFNOW" required >
```

Also, please try googling it, there're similar  questions like this answered also on StackOwerflow, e.g.

- html: [Can we match an exact string using html pattern attribute only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44932227/can-we-match-an-exact-string-using-html-pattern-attribute-only)
- js & php: [check if input value not equal to integer then don't submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43253698/check-if-input-value-not-equal-to-integer-then-dont-submit-form)

Comment: It'll not be an issue. I just want to to input the pattern. I have tried with adding the input pattern. But still no success. Pls refer the below code. <input class="form-control form-control-light bdr-2 rd-0" required data-label="Promo Code" data-msg="Please enter a valid promo code." type="text" name="promo-code" placeholder="Promo Code" pattern="15OFFNOW" required >

Comment: you are posting it with ajax, aren't you? that bypasses the pattern, therefore you should validate it in before posting it or even on server side

Comment: Maybe that's the issue. I'm using a pre-designed template.

Comment: Yes, that's the reason it's not working (pattern is an html5 attribute, however ajax skips this and some more html5 attributes afaik). Do you have an access to the script?

Comment: Yes. I have the access.

Comment: They you should simply check the promo code there like Pranav suggested :)